# Assign a value by looking up values in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

I have a dataframe (info) and a chromo below. Based on the information of `chromo[0]`, how can I assign the values in `chromo[1]` by looking up the information of `chromo[0]` in dataframe?

input:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Truck':  [2,4,3,1,6,5],
    'Door':   [1,6,5,2,3,4],
    'Status': [1,1,0,1,1,0]
})

chromo = [
    [3,6,1,2,5,4],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
#chromo[0] is Truck
#chromo[1] is Door
```

output:

```
chromo = [
    [3,6,1,2,5,4],
    [5,3,2,1,4,6]]
```

Comment: how about `chromo[1] = data.set_index("Truck").loc[chromo[0], "Door"].tolist()`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! I am not sure what this question is about: The output is your desired output? Why is chromo[0] matched to the Truck? Because it is most similar? How do you define if its similar or not, since there are no exact matches, or am I wrong=?